# mat-slider dynamic background color

Tags: angular, angular-material-6

I'd like to change the color of the mat-slider background based on the value, i.e. each value has an associated color.

I see that I can override the background-color like so:

```
::ng-deep .mat-accent .mat-slider-track-fill {
  background-color: red;
}
```

But how might I set it dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create CSS classes for each value/color, then use a dynamic container ID to override the child slider's CSS classes.

HTML

```
<div id="{{'container-' + slider.value}}">
  <md-slider #slider min="1" max="5" step="1" value="1"></md-slider>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container-1 /deep/ .mat-accent .mat-slider-track-fill {
  background: red!important;
}

#container-2 /deep/ .mat-accent .mat-slider-track-fill {
  background: blue!important;
}

#container-3 /deep/ .mat-accent .mat-slider-track-fill {
  background: green!important;
}

#container-4 /deep/ .mat-accent .mat-slider-track-fill {
  background: yellow!important;
}

#container-5 /deep/ .mat-accent .mat-slider-track-fill {
  background: purple!important;
}
```

Example stackblitz: https://angular-material-p9y14r.stackblitz.io

Comment: That's fantastic! Thank you!  I hadn't thought of tying it to an id.

Answer (score 2):

I would create CSS classes for each value/color, then use ngClass to dynamically assign.

HTML

```
<div id='container' [ngClass]="['slider-bg-' + slider.value]">
  <md-slider #slider min="1" max="5" step="1" value="1"></md-slider>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.slider-bg-1 {
  background-color: red;
}
.slider-bg-2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
.slider-bg-3 {
  background-color: green;
}
.slider-bg-4 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.slider-bg-5 {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

Example stackblitz: https://angular-material-dfpafj.stackblitz.io

Comment: Thanks, I worded the title poorly.  I'm not actually interested in changing the background-color, rather the '.mat-accent .mat-slider-track-fill' class. 






My confusion was about how to set that value since it doesn't seem like its directly on the mat-slider like the background-color is.

Comment: @Crhis, I've submitted a second answer that uses the same concept, but with a dynamic container ID that then overrides the CSS classes you've identified. Disclaimer, I've never used the deep selector. If you like the new answer better, I will delete the first.