# Set the html slider background programmatically in angular2

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I want to create a custom slider component, where the background color should be set with angular data binding.

Here is a simple [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-17hpul) where the default color green should be overridden/exchanged with the data-bound color red.

**What I tried:**

- I know that sliders aren't standardized and that every browser has it's [own representation](https://css-tricks.com/sliding-nightmare-understanding-range-input/)
- I can't create many css classes with ng-deep like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53710310/mat-slider-dynamic-background-color) because the background color should be data-bound.
- I tried with ngAfterViewInit() and document.getElementByID('slider'), but I can't get the access to the inner browser specific items (like webkit-slider-runnable-track)

**Question**

- Is there an "angular way" to create a property binding to background color of a slider?
- If not. Is there any way to set the background color of a slider within angular (with Javascript?)

Comment: did you try using css class?

Comment: do you need [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2p8ry2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the power of css variables.

**CSS**

```
.slider{
  --bg: green;
}

::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background:var(--bg);
}

::-ms-track {
  background: var(--bg);
}

::-moz-range-track {
  background: var(--bg);
}
```

HTML:

```
Set {{color}} as background for this slider:
<br />
<div class="slider" [attr.style]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle('--bg:' + color)">
    <input id='slider' type="range">
</div>
```

Here is the implementation: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oygzgp

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngClass to set your color dynamically

in your css.

```
.test::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: red ;
}

.test::-ms-track {
  background:red ;
}

.test::-moz-range-track {
  background: red ;
}
```

in your html:

```
<input id='slider' type="range" [ngClass]="isRed ? 'red' : 'green'">
```

Comment: I don't want create 16777216 classes for every possible RGB combination.